# Lerna, yarn, and Typescript: Cannot find module or its corresponding type declarations

Tags: typescript, yarnpkg, lerna, yarn-workspaces

I have a lerna + yarn workspaces monorepo, with independent versioning. I'm having trouble importing a package in its sibling.

I have two packages, one of which should depend on the other, as illustrated below:

```
(root)
  |--packages
       |--money
       |--money-standard-units
            |--{deps. on money}
```

Inside of `money-standard-deps`, I try to import an exported member of `money` but I'm unable to do so; I get the following message:

> TS2307: Cannot find module 'money' or its corresponding type declarations.

I know this issue can be resolved by adding `money` to the `paths` array of `money-standard-libs`'s tsconfig, but I want to depend on the *built* package as these will be published seperately. I want this to effectively work as-if it's two seperate repos.

I've created a [demo repo](https://github.com/jamescallumyoung/so-example-lerna-ts).

Comment: As this is very common, more clarifications are needed ... maybe a small github repo?

Comment: I thought that might be the case @gaitat. I've put a small example together and added the link to the question.

Comment: I cant really compile since there is no `@somescope` but maybe changing `export * from './monetary-unit';` to `export { MonetaryUnit } from './monetary-unit';` in money/src/index.ts

Comment: @gaitat could you specify what you mean by "there's no @somescope"? If you mean this scope isn't registered on npmjs.com, then that's exactly the point; these packages should be linked to locally.

Comment: I only meant that this `"dependencies": { "@somescope/money": "^0.0.0" }` will not resolve.

Comment: @gaitat, that's the issue I have. `import` statements in the `money-standard-units` package wont resolve. I get the error mentioned in the question.

Comment: So then this `export { MonetaryUnit } from './monetary-unit';` did not work?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228378/discussion-between-james-and-gaitat).

Comment: its a pity the linked monorepo is removed

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You will need to configure your typescript project to generate type declaration `*.d.ts` files if it is going to be used as a dependency of another typescript project. To do this, you will need to set the `compilerOptions.declaration` property of your tsconfig to `true`. You can do this in your [tsconfig-common.json](https://github.com/jamescallumyoung/so-example-lerna-ts/blob/master/tsconfig-common.json) file.

For example (tsconfig-common.json):

```
{
  ...
  "declaration": true
  ...
}
```

Additionally, in the same way you specify a `main` property in your `package.json` file to identify the entry file for your package you will also need to specify a `types` property to specify where your type declaration file is located. You need to do this for every package in your monorepo.

For example (package.json):

```
{
  "name": "@somescope/money",
  ...
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
  ...
}
```

Also, I noticed that you do a default export in your [monetary-unit](https://github.com/jamescallumyoung/so-example-lerna-ts/blob/master/packages/money/src/monetary-unit.ts#L1) module, but then do a named import for it in the [uses-money](https://github.com/jamescallumyoung/so-example-lerna-ts/blob/master/packages/money-standard-units/src/uses-money.ts#L1) module.

You will need to change the `monetary-unit` module to use a named export on the class if you intend to refer to it using a named import.

Example (monetary-unit.ts):

```
// Remove the default keyword
export class MonetaryUnit {
  constructor(
    readonly value: number,
    readonly name: string,
  ) {}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering @JoshA. This absolutely solved the problem and the packages can now be imported correctly. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Glad I could help. If you think I was able to answer your question, it would be great if you could mark it as answered. :-)

Comment: Absolutely! I was busy for a few days and wanted to check this worked in practice, with a complex example. It all works fine, I've marked you as the answer (any given the bounty). Thanks again.

Comment: The solution works! But the answer is still not marked! :p

Comment: One extra thing to check is that your package name is not the same as some public npm package. For instance, I had to change my local package name from auth  to my-auth